# Difference between "Jägermeister" and "Waidmann"

Tags: difference, usage, archaism

I learned a new German word today, *Waidmann*, but I already knew the word *Jägermeister*, so I wondered what the difference between them is. When would a German use one over the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the end both mean the same.

The usage of "Jägermeister" is obsolete. Nowadays when saying "Jägermeister" you usually refer to the alcoholic drink.

"Weidmann" or "Waidmann" is the technical term used by hunter and is also well known in "Weidmannsheil" and "Weidmannsdank", a greeting.

The informal term is just "Jäger"

Comment: @TecBrat: Unless you're very advanced, my advice is: for your active knowledge, forget "Waidmann" and learn "Jäger".

Comment: I'm definately not "very advanced". I can say "Es tut mir leid, mein Deutsch is nicht so gut." with the best of them though. :-)

Comment: Saying "Waidmann" is obsolete, but understanding the term is essential when a Jäger says "Waidmanns Heil!", this not being a neo-nazi phrase, but a "May thou be successfull!" shout between Jäger persons. Needless to say :-|

Comment: Another use of "Waidmann" would be in poetic language.

Comment: The normal word is Jäger. If someone would say  Waidmann in normal language this would be ridiculous. And Jägermeister is no variant for Jäger, it is alcohol sold with the brandname Jägermeister.

Answer (score 11):

They both mean the same thing, a *hunter*. According to Wikipedia, a Jägermeister was quite literally a master hunter.

Note, though, that today, under pretty much all circumstances, "Jägermeister" will be confused with the [liqueur of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A4germeister), and "Waidmann/Weidmann" is an outdated term that may not be understood at all except for the "Waidmanns Heil" ("good luck") expression.

Comment: Careful: "Waidmanns Heil" is *not* equivalent to "good luck".  So if you want to say "Good luck", you'd better say "Viel Glück".  "Waidmanns Heil" usually does have a hunting conotation or evokes/requires some kind of hunting context.  If someone told me she was hunting a bug in her code, I could respond with "Waidmanns Heil".  Jokingly :D

Comment: A Jägermeister was not "quite literally a master hunter", he *was* a master hunter. A Waidmann was just a simple huntsman, a Jäger, not a master. But the terms were in use at different times.

Answer (score 7):

Occupational titles change with the society that bestows them.

**Jägermeister** is an obsolete occupational title for a professional* hunter after a three year apprenticeship and an examination for a master craftsman's certificate (Meisterprüfung). It was current from around 1600 until the early 20th century. Today it is the name of a popular digestif (Kräuterlikör).

**Waidmann** – originally referring to anyone catching any kind of animal, later having the two more specific meanings "fisher" and "hunter" – is an even older occupational title, which was slowly displaced by "Jäger" from around 1600 onwards. It survives in popular folk songs and poetry when a romantic image of a huntsman is to be evoked, as well as in traditionalist hunter's lore.

**Jagdmeister** The job titles today are "Revierjäger", "Revierjagdmeister" (after a Meisterprüfung), Revieroberjäger (after 10 years as Jagdmeister) and Wildmeister (after 10 years as Oberjäger). [Source: http://www.revierjaeger.de/ernennungen]

**professional here meaning a job, not the quality*

Answer (score 0):

Waidmann/Weidmann has it's origin in the verb "auswaiden" which means taking the guts out of an animal. So a Waidmann is s.o. who hunts animals and can take their guts out and prepare them to be edible. Jäger/Jägersmann (Jägermeister (old)) do pretty much the same but it's shorter so more common and more often used.

Comment: That's a fairly limited description of Waidmann; compare Wikipedia.

Comment: Hast Du eine Quellenangabe für die Erklärung, dass Waidmann von "ausweiden" stammen soll?